# Is there a clean way to test ActiveRecord callbacks in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, callback

Suppose I have the following ActiveRecord class:

```
class ToastMitten < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :brush_off_crumbs
end
```

Is there a clean way to test that `:brush_off_crumbs` has been set as a `before_save` callback?

By "clean" I mean:

1. "Without actually saving", because

   - It's slow
   - I don't need to test that ActiveRecord correctly **handles** a `before_save` directive; I need to test that I correctly **told** it what to do before it saves.
2. "Without hacking through undocumented methods"

I found a way that satisfies criteria #1 but not #2:

```
it "should call have brush_off_crumbs as a before_save callback" do
  # undocumented voodoo
  before_save_callbacks = ToastMitten._save_callbacks.select do |callback|
    callback.kind.eql?(:before)
  end

  # vile incantations
  before_save_callbacks.map(&:raw_filter).should include(:brush_off_crumbs)
end
```

Answer (score 11):

## Use `run_callbacks`

This is less hacky, but not perfect:

```
it "is called as a before_save callback" do
  revenue_object.should_receive(:record_financial_changes)
  revenue_object.run_callbacks(:save) do
    # Bail from the saving process, so we'll know that if the method was 
    # called, it was done before saving
    false 
  end
end
```

Using this technique to test for an `after_save` would be more awkward.

Comment: this is the most elegant way i've seen! thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there anything like `run_callbacks` for controller callbacks?

Comment: For an `after_save`, you could probably just put the `should_receive` inside the block and return true, i.e.:   
  `revenue_object.run_callbacks(:save) do;
    revenue_object.should_receive(:record_financial_changes); true;
  end`